# Apache Spark unable to recognize columns in UTF-16 csv file

Tags: python, apache-spark, azure-databricks, spark-notebook

**Question**: Why I am getting following error on the last line of the code below, how the issue can be resolved?

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'OrderID'

**CSV File encoding**: UTF-16 LE BOM

**Number of columns**: 150

**Rows**: 5000

**Language etc.**: Python, Apache Spark, Azure-Databricks

**MySampleDataFile.txt**:

```
FirstName~LastName~OrderID~City~.....
Kim~Doe~1234~New York~...............
Bob~Mason~456~Seattle~...............
..................
```

**Code sample**:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType
df = spark.read.option("encoding","UTF-16LE").option("multiline","true").csv("abfss://mycontainder@myAzureStorageAccount.dfs.core.windows.net/myFolder/MySampleDataFile.txt", sep='~', escape="\"", header="true", inferSchema="false")
    
    display(df.limit(4))
df1 = df.withColumn("OrderID", df.OrderID.cast(DoubleType()))
```

**Output of display(df.limit(4))** It successfully displays the content of df in a tabular format with column header - similar to the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/getting-started/spark/dataframes#--view-the-dataframe):

```
---------------------------------------
|FirstName|LastName|OrderID|City|.....|
---------------------------------------
|Kim~Doe|1234|New York|...............|
|Bob|Mason|456|Seattle|...............|
|................                     |
---------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'OrderID'

> how the issue can be resolved?

You can try the following way to change the `data type`.

```
df1 = df.withColumn("OrderID", df[“OrderID”].cast(DoubleType()))
```

**OR** - *Alternative way,*

`pyspark.sql.functions.col` It will return a column depending on the name of the provided `column`.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col  
df1 = df.withColumn("OrderID", col("OrderID").cast(DoubleType()))
```

Comment: Your first suggestion worked (thank you). I've not tested the second suggestion but it does not mean it won't work. The issue seems to be related to `UTF-16`. The code in my post works fine if the dat files has `UTF-8'  encoding.